# Conditional Deleting in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, delete-row

See the SQL table below:

```
+------------+---------+
|  Category  | RevCode |
+------------+---------+
| 100.10.10  |       2 |
| 100.10.10  |       3 |
| 100.50.10  |       2 |
| 100.50.15  |       2 |
| 100.50.15  |       3 |
| 1000.80.10 |       3 |
| 200.10.10  |       3 |
| 200.50.10  |       3 |
| 200.80.10  |       3 |
| 2000.20.10 |       2 |
| 2000.20.10 |       3 |
| 2000.20.20 |       2 |
| 2000.20.20 |       3 |
| 2000.20.30 |       2 |
+------------+---------+
```

How can I delete all line items with the Rev Code of 3 where the following condition is met:
A Category has a Rev Code of both '2' and '3'.

For example:

```
+-----------+---------+
| Category  | RevCode |
+-----------+---------+
| 100.10.10 |       2 |
| 100.10.10 |       3 |
+-----------+---------+
```

The above table will become:

```
+-----------+---------+
| Category  | RevCode |
+-----------+---------+
| 100.10.10 |       2 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Go ahead. Give us your best shot.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: This is MSSQL Server 2012

Comment: @PM 77-1 I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Your sample already has the answer in it. from the main table select all category that has the revcode 2 and 3. from there start deleting all category that has the revcode 3. you probably should accept the answer given below

Answer (score 6):

You can use sub_query  with having clause like this:

```
delete from del_table
where RevCode = '3' 
  and  Category  in 
    (select Category from del_table 
     where RevCode in ('2','3')
     group by Category 
     having count(distinct RevCode) =2 )
```

this statement may not be efficient, you can use exists clause instead of in clause.

Thanks for  Charlesliam's comment. I use sql fiddle tested two cases below.

case1 :

```
create table del_table(Category varchar(20),RevCode Int);
INSERT INTO  del_table VALUES 
('100.10.10',2 ),
('100.10.10',3 ),
('100.50.10',2 ),
('100.50.15',3 )

result after deletion:
CATEGORY    REVCODE
100.10.10   2
100.50.10   2
100.50.15   3
```

case2(a Category have more than two rows with duplicate RevCode) :

```
create table del_table(Category varchar(20),RevCode Int);
INSERT INTO  del_table VALUES 
('100.10.10',2 ),
('100.10.10',2 ),
('100.10.10',3 ),
('100.10.10',3 ),
('100.50.10',2 ),
('100.50.15',3 )

result after deletion:
CATEGORY    REVCODE
100.10.10   2
100.10.10   2
100.50.10   2
100.50.15   3
```

Comment: It could actually be [much simpler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6d35c/9): `... and Category in (select Category from del_table where RevCode = '2')`.

Answer (score 1):

See whether this helps you.

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, CATEGORY VARCHAR(20),REVCODE INT)
INSERT INTO @A VALUES 
('100.10.10',2 ),
('100.10.10',3 ),
('100.50.10',2 ),
('100.50.15',2 ),
('100.50.15',3 ),
('1000.80.10',3),
('200.10.10',3 ),
('200.50.10',3 ),
('200.80.10',3 ),
('2000.20.10',2),
('2000.20.10',3),
('2000.20.20',2),
('2000.20.20',3),
('2000.20.30',2)

SELECT * FROM @A
```

Table:

[image]

Query:

```
DELETE  LU
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CATEGORY ORDER BY REVCODE) ROW 
        FROM    @A A
        WHERE   A.REVCODE IN (2,3)
        ) LU
WHERE   LU.ROW = 2

SELECT * FROM @A
```

Result:

[image]